# How to fix sphere after Boolean with cylinder?

Tags: mesh, faces, boolean-modifier

If i knew how to look this up I would, after i used a Boolean operation on what essentially is a sphere, I get these ugly broken faces. What can I do to correct this or how can I get a similar effect without using Boolean?

[image]

[image: Mesh with "broken" faces after Boolean operation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a clean topology, you should better do it this way: Create a sphere, mirror it, cut several faces where you want to create the eye, give it a *Shrinkwrap* modifier with another sphere underneath as target, select the edges around the hole:

[image]

Extrude inwards and right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (enable the *LoopTools* addon if it isn't the case yet):

[image]

Apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier, hide the target sphere, fill the face, extrude inwards:

[image]

Bevel the edges, tweak the parameters in the *Operator Box*:

[image]

Move some vertices if necessary (double <kbd>G</kbd> to slide along the edges):

[image]

Result with a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a Treasure.